# instead of Currency convertor, want to set fixed price set to price to Products

Tags: magento2, multicurrency, switcher

I have Magento 2 setup, having one website and 2 stores. I want 5 different currencies in my store. Instead of using the Magento currency converter, I want to set a fixed price for all different currencies.
i.e.
Product one has 5 currencies attributes (Price_KWD, Price_BHS, Price_US, Price_OMR, Price_AED, Price_QAR). If I change the currency from Price_KWD to Price_BHS, then it will show the value Price_BHS

Product Price_KWD =10
Product Price_BHS=20

On conversion, It should show 20 with a currency symbol.
see URL for reference http://autoone.viewmysitenow.com/

Answer (score 0):

The most granular scope for the price attribute in Magento is website.
You can not set a fixed price for different currencies under the same store view. If you want to have different currencies on the same store view you will have to use the currency converter, however as I understand this will not work for you.

Unfortunately you will have to set up 5 different website which are connected to 5 different store views and set the price scope to website, then you can use the store view switcher in the catalog to set a different price for every store view.

Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Price -> Catalog Price Scope  and set to Website